# Using AWS SES SMTP- error 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ses

Getting this error on the email address I am trying to send an email to!

Not sure why I need to verify an email I am sending to which doesn't belong to me?

DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region EU-WEST-1: danielhaughton@outlook.com

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("app.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {
@Autowired
private Environment env;
@Bean
public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost("email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");
    mailSender.setPort(25);
    mailSender.setUsername("removedcreds");
    mailSender.setPassword("removed creds");
    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    return mailSender;
}
```

EmailService
    @Component
    public class EmailServiceImpl  {

```
@Autowired
public JavaMailSender emailSender;

public void sendSimpleMessage(String toAddress, String subject, String text) 
{
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setTo(toAddress);
    message.setFrom("noreply@mydomain.com");
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(text);
    emailSender.send(message);
}
}
```

My emailserviceimpl is autowird into a web controller that I send the email from

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By Default you AWS Account's SES capabilities are sandboxed, and being in SES sandbox comes with certain restrictions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

> To help protect our customers from fraud and abuse and to help you
>   establish your trustworthiness to ISPs and email recipients, we do not
>   immediately grant unlimited Amazon SES usage to new users. New users
>   are initially placed in the Amazon SES sandbox. In the sandbox, you
>   have full access to all Amazon SES email-sending methods and features
>   so that you can test and evaluate the service; however, the following
>   restrictions are in effect:
>
> You can only send mail to the Amazon SES mailbox simulator and **to
>   verified email addresses** and domains.
>
> You can only send mail from verified email addresses and domains.
>
> You can send a maximum of 200 messages per 24-hour period.
>
> Amazon SES can accept a maximum of one message from your account per
>   second.

See this blog post that outlines steps to get out of sandbox.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/ses-limit-increase-form-consolidation/

Answer (score 9):

Follow the step to verify your email.

[image: Do the following steps to verify your email]

Comment: This setting is now under: Configuration -> Verified identities -> Create identity

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your account from `sandbox-mode` to `production`.

Additional information is available here :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/request-production-access.html